# Have you an idea? Do you have an idea?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

I've seen an expression, "Have you an idea?"

Is it always possible to say "have you ~?" instead of "do you have~?"

"Have you a pen?"

"Do you have a pen?"

"Have you got a pen?"

Are they all OK and the same?

Comment: Discussed recently under [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311535/why-is-has-the-item-low-reliability-a-correct-sentence/311537#311537)

Answer (score -1):

As an aside, there may be regional (national) and class variations in this usage.

When I started school in England (my previous schooling was French in Canada), if someone asked me a question, "Do you have [a pen]?" then I'd be inclined to answer "Yes I do." And young boys mocked me for that, because the proper/grammatical answer should have been "Yes I have."

I think that "have got" is used in fact, but is vulgar -- I don't mean rude, but unschooled -- or I might say, it's "familiar" i.e. I'd say it to my mother or brother, who don't correct my grammar.

And "have you" sounds formal -- maybe too formal, overly schooled, or English-as-a-second-language.

So I'd say "Do you have" (or depending on context, "may I borrow" or "can you lend me" or "would you lend me").

---

**Lucy says to Snoopy "Have you any idea what you're going to do with the rest of your life?"**

IMO using "any" instead of "an" changes the rhythm of the sentence i.e. which of the words receive emphasis when spoken:

1. **Have** you an **idea**?
2. Do-you **have** an **idea**?
3. **Have** you **an**-y **idea**?

I might avoid the first one in my normal speech because the middle words "you an" come out kind of mumbled.

Comment: "maybe too formal, overly schooled, or English-as-a-second-language." - none of these in British English, but a bit old-fashioned perhaps.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: You said that 'have you' sounds 'formal -- maybe too formal, overly schooled, or English-as-a-second-language.'. I disagreed with all three, but added 'but a bit old-fashioned perhaps'.

Comment: Ah -- you're saying it's normal or not abnormal in British English.

Comment: A bit 'posh' (slightly formal) maybe.

Comment: That's what I meant by "schooled", i.e. it's something like Oxford English (which I learned from my Dad -- according to my Mum he originally spoke Nottingham English, so there's some "English as a second language" too!).

Comment: My dad originally spoke 'Derby English' but had it knocked out of him at Loughborough Grammar School between 1931 and 1937, and he said 'have you...'.

Comment: But I found this phrase in Peanuts.  Lucy says to Snoopy "Have you any idea what you're going to do with the rest of your life?"  Linus may use some old-fashioned English, but it is Lucy.  I don't think she would ever use formal or old-fashioned English when she talks to a dog.

Comment: @kuwabara "Have you any idea..." is a fixed phrase used in formal and informal English.

Comment: And Charles Schultz was writing for publication, in newspapers -- not very informal -- and in comic form might prefer whichever version has fewer words.